# Javascript Reset for clipboard and table application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not able to copy everything from the text are though, I was hoping on how do I get to set a reset button or at least bing f5 key to another button to reset the form when I need to.

I'm still learning, any advise is greatly appreciated.

Also is there a way I can put this thing in a Box? like a table where it would look a bit professional.
i attached a picture on what I was hoping to get vs to what I have now

[image]

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Shin</title>

</head>
<body>
 <center>
<textarea id="text" cols="80" rows="34" >
SESA
Caller's Name:
Call back number:
Email Address:
Related case #s (case history):
Location, remote/hotel/office:

Application Name: 
Number of Users Affected: Number of Users Affected: (Single User / Less than 5 users / 5 or more users)

What is the issue/problem:
When did the issue/problem begin:
Login id:  
Error message (if any):
When was the last time it worked properly:
Have there been any changes to your PC since the last time it worked properly:
Have you changed your password recently:

Troubleshooting steps (detailed):

Additional Detail (links, screen shots etc.. :


Resolution:
A - problem:
B - cause:
C - actions:
D - resolution:
----------------------------------------------------------</textarea><br>
<button onclick="copy()">Copy</button><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
function copy () {
 var text = document.getElementById('text');
 var range = document.createRange();

 range.selectNode(text);
 window.getSelection().addRange(range);
 document.execCommand('copy');
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For the second question I would use something like a [form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: tried to find one but there's no copy feature..this one is giving me a headache